# Catch Python Cloud Storage Errors

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-cloud-storage

I'm presently going over the error handling of a Cloud Run application, and I've noticed it's not capturing the errors and exiting gracefully as I would like. Consider the following:

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket(input_bucket)
try:
   blob = bucket.get_blob(input_file)
except Exception as e:
   logger.log_struct(
      {"ext_file_id": ext_file_id,
      "output_bucket": output_bucket,
      "status": "Failure",
      "error_message": e,
      "tags": tags},
      resource=res, severity='ERROR')
   return ("", 400)
```

For my testing, I've deliberately removed the service account permissions from the storage bucket.
When testing locally with:

```
try:
  blob = blob = bucket.get_blob(input_file)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

This returns the error message as expected:
"403 GET [https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[BLOB_NAME]?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false](https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/%5BBUCKET_NAME%5D/o/%5BBLOB_NAME%5D?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false): [ServiceAccount@...] does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."

However, my code above doesn't give me the structed error log as I expect; instead it produces a very long traceback, and then continues to reproduce the error until I purge Pub/Sub that triggers Cloud Run.

I've attempted to employ the exceptions module (*from google.cloud import storage, exceptions*), but it's not particularly clear how to use that:

```
try:
  blob = blob = bucket.get_blob(input_file)
except exceptions.Forbidden:
  print(exceptions.Forbidden) # This give me the object
  print(exceptions.Forbidden.code) # This gives me HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN
```

Yet if I reprint *exceptions.Forbidden.code*, it gives me: *<HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN: 403>*.

I could potentially work with this if I could get the 403 HTTPStatus to show initially, but ideally I need to capture the error message and display the structured error regardless of what HTTP error message is received (404,403, etc.).

Comment: 1) You are using the term "structured error". What this that? If you do not want long displays of the exception, don't convert the exception into a string `print(e)`. Instead, use the members of the exception for the information you want. 2) If you return an error while processing a message, the message will be retried at a late time. I am not sure of the point you were making (you want retries or you do not want retries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is a simple example for figuring out what attributes the exceptions from `google-api-core` have, using pythons built-in `dir()` function. [Reading material.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dir-function/)

The ones you're interested in are the public ones, eg without the leading underscore(s)...

```py
from google.cloud import exceptions
from pprint import pprint


try:
    raise exceptions.NotFound('message goes here')
except Exception as e:
    pprint(dir(e))
    print()
    print(e.message)
```

**output:**

```py
['__cause__',
 '__class__',
 '__context__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__suppress_context__',
 '__traceback__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_errors',
 '_response',
 'args',
 'code',
 'errors',
 'grpc_status_code',
 'message',
 'response',
 'with_traceback']

message goes here
```

Comment: e.message was exactly what I was looking for - doh! Thanks very much! (When you know, you know, but when you don't it can be an absolute pain :))